# Virtualbox, Windows 7 guest and 3D acceleration

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox

I have a Debian 7 host, with Virtualbox 4.2.12, Virtualbox Extension Pack, and a Windows 7 Professional Guest, with Virtualbox Guest Additions enabled, and 3D acceleration enabled (had to go to safe mode).

With this configuration, I'm not able to get 3D acceleration to work.

If it is disabled, everything works fine, except the games I'd like to play.

If it is enabled, then the programs aren't displayed correctly:

Google Chrome is shown like this
[image: like this]

Also the game I'd like to play creates a black window, and only shows one quarter of the screen.

As said, if I disable 3D acceleration, Chrome works fine, but the game doesn't load.

Comment: I'm not sure but I think you have to load the driver, once Guest additions has been loaded. Here is the link to the virtual Box manual. Check section 4 > Hardware - accelerated graphics. http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/UserManual.html#id2636938

Comment: I read all the section 4, and it says how to enable it: Direct3D or Aero (neither of those work). I enabled an Aero Windows 7 theme, and it seems to work. Thank you for your answer.